# IntelliJ Idea: how to get a plugin path at runtime

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need to get the path of a plugin inside of the actionPerformed method of one of its AnAction when it is invoked

Answer (score 2):

`com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager#getPluginsPath`

or

`com.intellij.openapi.application.PluginPathManager#getPluginHome`